# Can't access property from object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

**EDIT: Re-structured question, cleaer, and cleaner:**

I have a `data` object from Sequelize that is sent by node-express:

```
{
    "page": 0,
    "limit": 10,
    "total": 4,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "movies",
            "isActive": true,
            "createdAt": "2020-05-30T19:26:04.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-30T19:26:04.000Z",
            "questions": [
                {
                    "questionsCount": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The BIG question is, **how do I get the value of `questionsCount`?**
The PROBLEM is, I just can't extract it, these two methods give me `undefined` result:

1. `category.questions[0].questionsCount`
2. `category.questions[0]['questionsCount']`

I WAS ABLE to get it using `toJSON()` (From Sequelize lib I think), like so:

```
category.questions[0].toJSON().questionsCount
```

But I'd like to know the answer to the question, or at least a clear explanation of why do I have to use `toJSON()` just to get the `questionsCount`?

---

More context:

I have this `GET` in my controller:

```
exports.getCategories = (req, res) => {
  const page = myUtil.parser.tryParseInt(req.query.page, 0)
  const limit = myUtil.parser.tryParseInt(req.query.limit, 10)

  db.Category.findAndCountAll({
    where: {},
    include: [
      {
        model: db.Question,
        as: "questions",
        attributes: [[db.Sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'id'), 'questionsCount']]
      }
    ],
    offset: limit * page,
    limit: limit,
    order: [["id", "ASC"]],
  })
    .then(data => {

      data.rows.forEach(function(category) {
        console.log("------ May 31 ----> " + JSON.stringify(category.questions[0]) + " -->" + category.questions[0].hasOwnProperty('questionsCount'))
        console.log(JSON.stringify(category))
        console.log(category.questions[0].toJSON().questionsCount)
      })

      res.json(myUtil.response.paging(data, page, limit))
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error get categories: " + err.message)
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "An error has occured while retrieving data."
      })
    })
}
```

I loop through the `data.rows` to get each `category` object.

The `console.log` outputs are:

```
------ May 31 ----> {"questionsCount":4} -->false

{"id":1,"title":"movies","isActive":true,"createdAt":"2020-05-30T19:26:04.000Z","updatedAt":"2020-05-30T19:26:04.000Z","questions":[{"questionsCount":4}]}

4
```

Comment: Why don't you *log* `data`, `data.rows`, or `category` itself, instead of pulling your hair out?

Comment: Although I’m newbie in js, I reckon an experienced programmer from other platform would certainly think about doing that before taking an effort to post a question on Stackoverflow. The logs didn’t help. I haven’t checked the answer below but after an hour, I was able to solve this problem using [0].toJSON()

Comment: Added the console.log above.

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(category)` instead of `console.log(JSON.stringify(category))`? The problem is that `JSON.stringify` already calls `toJSON()` before stringifying, so you don't see what is really there.

Comment: `toJSON()` is the key, look at the first bullet point here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description - `JSON.stringify()` calls `toJSON()`, when it is present. That's how the missing field miraculously pops up in the log.

Comment: Or actually, I'd be most interested in what `console.log(category.questions[0])` gives.

Comment: By the way, the trick to keep the nice object output together with other things in the log statement is to use multiple parameters and not `+`, for example `console.log('Question data', category.questions[0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/docs/manual/core-concepts/model-querying-finders.md

> By default, the results of all finder methods are instances of the model class (as opposed to being just plain JavaScript objects). This means that after the database returns the results, Sequelize automatically wraps everything in proper instance objects. In a few cases, when there are too many results, this wrapping can be inefficient. To disable this wrapping and **receive a plain response instead, pass { raw: true } as an option to the finder method**.

(emphasis by me)
Or directly in the source code, https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/59b8a7bfa018b94ccfa6e30e1040de91d1e3d3dd/lib/model.js#L2028

> @returns {Promise<{count: number, rows: Model[]}>}

So the thing is that you get an array of `Model` objects which you could navigate with their `get()` method. It's an unfortunate coincidence that you expected an array, and got an array so you thought it is "that" array. Try the `{raw:true}` thing, I guess it looks something like this:

```
db.Category.findAndCountAll({
    where: {},
    include: [
      {
        model: db.Question,
        as: "questions",
        attributes: [[db.Sequelize.fn('COUNT', 'id'), 'questionsCount']]
      }
    ],
    offset: limit * page,
    limit: limit,
    order: [["id", "ASC"]],
    raw: true                            // <--- hopefully it is this simple
  }) [...]
```

---

`toJSON()` is nearby too, https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/59b8a7bfa018b94ccfa6e30e1040de91d1e3d3dd/lib/model.js#L4341

> ```
>   /**
>    * Convert the instance to a JSON representation.
>    * Proxies to calling `get` with no keys.
>    * This means get all values gotten from the DB, and apply all custom getters.
>    *
>    * @see
>    * {@link Model#get}
>    *
>    * @returns {object}
>    */
>   toJSON() {
>     return _.cloneDeep(
>       this.get({
>         plain: true
>       })
>     );
>   }
> ```

So it worked exactly because it did what you needed, removed the `get()` stuff and provided an actual JavaScript object matching your structure (POJSO? - sorry, I could not resist). I rarely use it and thus always forget, but the key background "trick" is that a bit contrary to its name, `toJSON()` is not expected to create the actual JSON string, but to provide a replacement object which still gets stringified by `JSON.stringify()`. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
category.data[0].questions[0].questionCount
```

the reason why you have to use toJSON is because it's sometimes it is used to customise the stringification behavior. like doing some calculation before assinging the value to the object that will be returned , so it is most likley been used here to calculate the "numb of questions and then return an object with the property questionscount and the number calculated
so the object you retreived more or less looks like this

```
var cathegory = {
  data: 'data',
  questions:[{
    // some calulation here to get the questionsCount 
      result=4,
    toJSON () {
      return  {"questionsCount":this.result}       
    } 
  }
 ]
};

console.log(cathegory.questions[0].toJSON().questionsCount) //4
console.log(JSON.stringify(cathegory))  // {"data":"data","questions":[{"questionsCount":4}]}
console.log("------ May 31 ----> " + JSON.stringify(cathegory.questions[0]) + " -->" + cathegory.questions[0].hasOwnProperty('questionsCount')) //false
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do so `category.data[0].questions.questionCount`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others already, you need `category.data[0].questions[0].questionCount`.

Let me add to that by showing you why. Look at your object, I annotated it with how each part would be accessed:

```js
category = { // category
    "page": 0,
    "limit": 10,
    "total": 2,
    "data": [ // category.data
        { // category.data[0]
            "id": 1,
            "title": "movies",
            "createdAt": "2020-05-30T19:26:04.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-30T19:26:04.000Z",
            "questions": [ // category.data[0].questions
                { // category.data[0].questions[0]
                    "questionCount": 2 // category.data[0].questions[0].questionCount
                }
            ],
            "questionsCount": "newValue here!"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, although I’ve solved this problem, I’d like it if someone can figure this problem out. Your answer technically should help, BUT TRUST ME, that did not work, really. If you could explain why the way I solved it worked (see comment in my question), and this answer won’t (similar to the methods I described in my question), then I’m definitely choosing this as answer.

Comment: I don't really understand what you did with `toJSON` though. What is the exact code you ended up using?

Comment: I am getting the feeling that the `this is a category data` that you posted, which all our answers based on, is a red herring. Is it possible that this is the output of `JSON.stringify` and not `util.inspect` so that it already got processed by a custom `toJSON` implementation of your framework? What is the framework, by the way? It sounds as if your `toJSON` way is not the way your framework "wants" you to access this data, and I'm trying to figure out what the proper way is.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. Please see my updated answer. The whole response is called `Category`, you're right. And for each `category` object, there are many `question` objects. The `toJSON()` I think is from `Sequelize` library. It's bugging me. I'll try it now to confirm that both `category.questions[0]['questionCount']` and `category.questions[0].questionCount` do not work.

Comment: I have a feeling that the reason that I had to call `toJSON()` from `category.questions[0]` is because that question object is a Sequelize instance, and it's not a mere simple object. But please feel pree to add more explanation and then lets get this question closed.

Comment: Hey man, I edited my question from scratch. It's now clearer, if you have time, I'd love it if you could take a look at it.

Comment: i have explained why you have to use toJSON() and updated my answer